# How does javascript x = y work when dealing with objects?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, adobe-analytics

I am working with Omniture tagging and I've got numerous events on the page.  In omniture, the base object is `s` this object is created globally by Omniture.

The `s` object has a number of "standard" variables that I like to set for it, url, pagetitle, time on site, what have you...

For each event I set one or two additional properties

I thought I was being really clever in writing functions like:

```
 //  s is a global variable create by omniture

 function ClickFoo(){
      var s_ = s;  // make a copy of s which has all the standard vars
      s_.event = "Click Foo";  // set X number of custom vars 
      s_.prop1 = "foo";
      s_.t();    // the Omniture "submit event" function
 }

 function ClickBar(){
      var s_ = s;
      s_.event = "Click Bar";
      s_.prop2 = "bar";
      s_.t();    
 }

 ClickFoo();
 ClickBar();
 // at this point, s.prop1 = "foo"
```

If the user clicks `foo` then `bar` the `s_.prop1` object property is set on the bar submit.

I've been looking at the behavior of this stuff in the JS console and it seems that changes to s_ have an effect on the global object s.

Can anyone explain how the assignment is working so I don't make this mistake in future?  Is there a quick way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you basically have at first is an object and a variable referencing it:

[image]

What you're then doing is setting another variable to the same object:

[image]

So when altering `_s`, you're dealing with the exact same object as `s` and hence you get those altered values with `s` as well.

Instead, you want two different objects, basically clones:

[image]

There are several clone snippets available. In jQuery, it's as easy as `$.extend({}, obj)`, and in vanilla JavaScript [this one](http://blog.imaginea.com/deep-copy-in-javascript/) can be used for example.

Comment: if you're using ExtJS:var cloneS = Ext.extend(S, {});

Answer (score 5):

`var _s = s;` is not copying `s`, but makes both `_s` and `s` reference the same object. You will need to either create a new object or copy the properties of the original object into _s. There are [**clone methods**](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165) you could use:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
};

...
var _s = s.clone(); // _s now does not reference the same object as s
```

Answer (score 3):

When you assign an object to a variable, the reference to the variable is copied. The object is not "cloned" in any way.  So:

```
var a = {},
    b = a;

b.foo = 'bar';
alert(a.foo); // 'bar'
```

This is intentional behaviour. (As a side point, the only time when `a == b` if `a` and `b` are objects is if they are references to the *same* object.)

If you want to deliberately clone an object, it's a little trickier.  If you have a modern browser, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to clone an object effectively:

```
var a = {},
    b = Object.create(a);

b.foo = 'bar';
alert(a.foo); // undefined
```

You can patch this behaviour into your application by using the method in that MDN page:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.');
        }
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

[<sub>From MDN</sub>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill)

So if you use this code, you could then do this at the top of your methods:

```
var s_ = Object.create(s);
```

You would then be working on separate objects and the problems you found would not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Think of references being decoupled from objects.

_s and s are both references. In the statement,

```
var _s = s;
```

you are copying the referenced value in s to _s. So they now refer to the same object.